# Why are javascript modules deferred by default?

Tags: javascript, es6-modules

It's [said](https://v8.dev/features/modules#defer) that js modules are deferred by default. And there is no way to undo this apparently. I'm curious: why? Is it due to how modules are loaded internally that it's impossible to load them as usual? Or did they deem the (previously) default behavior useless as you are unlikely to want to block html parser while loading the script?